# Accessing index of model array using $index within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a web page where the user has to enter details about their friends like names, emails etc. The number of friends they need to enter this for is dynamic and I want to store each friends' details in a model. So far I'm doing something like this with my markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in getNoOfFriends() track by $index">
    <form name="friendForm">
        <input type="text" ng-model="friends[$index].firstName">
    </form>
</div>
```

And in my controller:

```
function SignupController($scope, $rootScope, $location, $routeParams, params, API, Context) {
    $scope.friends = [];
    $scope.noOfFriends = 2;

    $scope.preSaveFriends = function() {
        var emptyFriend = {
            firstName: ''
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.noOfFriends; i++) {
            $scope.friends.push(emptyFriend);
        }
    };
    $scope.preSaveFriends();
}
SignupController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'params', 'API', 'Context'];
```

When the page loads and the controller first runs, `$scope.friends` is populated with empty objects with the property `firstName`. What I'm trying to do is for each form that's generated in the HTML (using `ng-repeat`) update the model for that particular friend.

At the moment it seems to be updating the `firstName` property for *every* friend in `$scope.friends`. When I type their first name into the input element, it's updated on every other friend as well.

How can I get set the model for this input to be a specific index of `$scope.friends`?

Comment: there are lots of missing code here. where is `getNoOfFriends`? where you use `preSaveFriends`? is your template inside another repeater? how your model is formed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a lot more natural to iterate over the `friends` array:

```
<div ng-repeat="friend in friends track by $index">
    <form name="friendForm">
        <input type="text" ng-model="friend.firstName">
    </form>
</div>
```

You'd need to prepopulate it, though:

```
// In controller.
var numFriends = 2;
while ($scope.friends.length < numFriends) {
    $scope.friends.push({});
}
```

Comment: I obviously need a break because this never occurred to me and is the simplest way of doing it. Thanks!